# Is it feasible to redirect all possible similar domain to one domain in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have below configuration but it only redirects my specified urls to target.fi,I want to make it more general and for any possible domain that contain "target" it will be redirected to my domain.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abctarget.fi bctarget.fi targetbcd.fi bc.target.fi;
    return 301 $scheme://target.fi;
}
```

How to make it like `server_name *target*.fi;`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ?;
    return 301 $scheme://target.fi;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a wildcard name. See [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names).